# Always show Icons in Tabs in Visual Studio 2013 (also in 2012)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Normally the Tabs in Visual Studio contains only text.

[image: Tabs with text]

But if there is not enough space there are icons instead of the text.

[image: Tabs with pictures]

Is it possible to always show these icons additionally to the text? Because I assume that this would really improve the readability.

Comment: I tried restoring and re-sizing visual studio 2013 but the caption of various windows or tabs showing code files always display text. They never display image. How did you resize your window to achieve this or there is any specific setting in tools -> options to achieve it. I'm unable to attach screenshot as stackoverflow comments don't allow it.

Comment: I just used the splitter to resize parts of the window, where the Tabs are. I also tried unpinning the Panels, but then it was not possible to resize them appropriate. It also helps, to have more Tabs then less (obvuiosly ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is **NOT** a way to show both the text AND icons, its either the text or the icon (when resizing the window). This is true for both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.